# What is the reading order for Kawaraya A-ta's Asuka and Rei (and sometimes Mari) H-Doujinshi?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion, doujinshi

There is an artist called Kawaraya A-ta who's done a bunch of H-Doujinshi featuring Asuka and Rei from Neon Genesis Evangelion as Futanari. the ones I have read (as in fan translated) are:

- Lovey Dovey
- Sin-Lovey Dovey
- Pokapoka Onedari Onsen
- Oomisoka
- Summer Memories
- Wokurimono
- Kashidashuchuu
- Please Punish Me!
- Princess and the Slave
- Spirit of Flower (Chapter 15 of Hana - Maki no)
- Flowers Breaking Through My Soul (Chapter 18 pf Hana - Maki no)
- Welcome Home
- Welcome Home 2

Well the Doujinshi get messy with all the bodily fluids I did enjoy the story behind them, particularly how in Lovey Dovey Asuka looses her memories yet Rei stays with her and Asuka proposes to Rei but when Asuka regains her memories and acts all Tsundere again she accepts Rei's proposal while in another one when Mari is living with them she seduces and has intercourse with Rei while on the phone with Asuka as a means to get her to admit that she actually loves Rei (as opposed to saying that Rei is just her Pet)

However while titles like Lovey Dovey and Welcome Home make it easy to work out when to read them the others I don't know when they are place as the site I read them on doesn't list publication year and at some point in them Mari turns up and while after this you would expect that Asuka wouldn't be acting all "I am your Master, do as I say" I'm not sure at what point in them this occurs as Asuka doesn't always play the Pet's Master card she is intimate with Rei even before the ones featuring Mari was uploaded.

I would like to know what is the reading order for Kawaraya A-ta's Asuka and Rei H-Doujinshi?

Comment: Heyyy. Ive read only one chapter out of all these and haven't read the other ones yet coz I'm still searching for the right order. It's been almost 5 years since this question has been posted so I'm hoping you've got the right order and also there are a couple new chapters. Can you tell me if you know about the reading order